# Error importing Python libraries installed with PIP inside Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pip, pybrain

I'm using Python 2.7.5 64 bits and I have a problem when importing libraries that were installed via PIP when importing them inside Eclipse (version 4.3.1). Outside Eclipse (directly in Python's shell) everything works fine, here is an example:

```
>>> import numpy                             # installed from repositories
>>> from numpy import array
>>> import pybrain                           # installed via PIP
>>> from pybrain import Network
>>>
```

Everything works outside Eclipse. But inside Eclipse I can't import libraries installed via PIP using "from x import y" format, it will give an error. The only way I can import libraries installed via PIP is using "import x" format. Here is an example:

```
import numpy                                     # no errors (installed from repositories)
from numpy import array                          # no errors
import pybrain                                   # no errors (installed via PIP)
from pybrain import Network                      # gives the error below

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/arquivos/pybrain_import_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pybrain import Network
ImportError: cannot import name Network
```

I suspected it could be related to **virtualenv**, but here is a [print screen](http://imageshack.com/a/img534/4307/3x0m.png) of my Python's PATH. The directory */usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages* where PyBrain is installed is already in Python's PATH inside Eclipse. Could someone help me, please?

EDIT: it's solved now, read my comment below to see the solution.

Comment: Make sure eclipse is using the right virtualenv.

Comment: PyBrain is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (according to PIP and I checked it myself too) and this directory is already in Eclipse's "SYSTEM PYTHONPATH Libraries". Check this printscreen, please, and see if there is something I'm missing: http://imageshack.com/a/img534/4307/3x0m.png

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694741/how-to-setup-pydevs-python-interpreter-in-eclipse-using-pip-within-a-virtualenv) may prove useful?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but PIP's official installation instructions don't say to install it using a virtualenv like the OP of this other thread is saying.

Comment: PS: I edited the post, so it will be more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved now! I created a package named "pybrain" for testing PyBrain module, so when I tryed to import something from PyBrain library, Python would import all modules from this personal package I created. The problem was not being reproduced outside Eclipse because only within Eclipse my personal workstation directory (which contained the personal package "pybrain") was visible. The solution was simple: I just deleted the personal package named "pybrain" and now everything is working. Thank you very much for your help!