# ImportError for cv2 with lackey in a virtualenv

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv, sikuli-script, lackey

**Big picture is**

In Windows 7, lackey installed with pip in a python3.6.1 virtualenv created with a python2.7.2 interpreter from an unpacked .tar.gz of virtualenv15.1.0 **can't import the cv2 module**.

**Context / Environment**

In Windows 7 (x64) with `C:\Users\user1>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\VirtualenvTools\virtualenv-15.1.0\virtualenv.py --python=C:\VirtualenvTools\Python36\Python.exe C:\virtualenvs\virtualenv` (*all one line*) I create a virtualenv  and set its *C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\Scripts\Python.exe* file as the main interpreter for a PyDev project in Eclipse.

I also installed lackey after entering the virtualenv with `activate` and then the `pip install lackey` command  @ the *C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\Scripts\* directory without any listed errors (installation worked).

**The problem**

When I import lackey with `from lackey import *` in my PyDev project, there is an `ImportError` from Eclipse's console.

The console's stackTrace:
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "C:\Users\user1\workspace\sikulixframework0.1\testManager.py", line 4, in <module>`
`from lackey import *`
`File "C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\lib\site-packages\lackey\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>`
`from .RegionMatching import Pattern, Region, Match, Screen, ObserveEvent`
`File "C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\lib\site-packages\lackey\RegionMatching.py", line 17, in <module>`
`import cv2`
`File "C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>`
`from . import cv2`
`ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.`

> (Le module spécifié est introuvable. = The specified module could not be found.)

When using the same interpreter (*C:\virtualenvs\virtualenvname\Scripts\Python.exe*) directly, if I write `from lackey import *` I get the same stackTrace

**My resolution tries**

I tried the same things (`from lackey import *`) outside a virtual environment and it worked. Like suggested in [an answer to the stackoverflow's question 'Can't import cv2; “DLL load failed”'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34390694/6529948), I downloaded the [Visual C++ 2015 redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) but nothing of my complications changed.

Comment: Maybe lackey just doesn't work nice within a virtualenv. Like google's app engine (pdb)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694741/how-to-setup-pydevs-python-interpreter-in-eclipse-using-pip-within-a-virtualenv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added, in the Windows PATH environment variable, the path to the original Python3.6.1 from the *path\to\original\python36\python.exe*  in `C:\Users\user1>C:\Python27\python.exe C:\VirtualenvTools\virtualenv.py --python=C:\VirtualenvTools\Python36\Python.exe C:\virtualenvs\virtualenv` command for the virtualenv's creation that contained that *python3.dll* file  and added that same *python3.dll* file in the *C:\virtualenvs\virtualenv\Scripts* directory and it worked!

**Summary if you use virtualenv and an ImportError occurs (for cv2 at least)**

1. Make sure that the path to the executable (which contains the *python3.dll* file in python3.6.1 at least) that is referenced by the virtualenv (after that `--python=` part of the creation command) is in the "PATH" Windows environment variable.
2. Add that same *python3.dll* file to the *\Scripts\* directory where the virtualenv is.

The lackey project git owner(glitchassassin)'s [answer](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey/issues/95) helped me resolve this issue. He also states that this problem is caused by virtualenv:

> Looks like this is actually also [an issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/796#issuecomment-269637305) in virtualenv.

On the issue of virtualenv, some people found the same solution:

> [N]o need to download DLL files from untrusted random Internet sites, just copy the one from c:/Python3.5/ (or wherever you installed Python 3.5) into any directory on your %PATH%.